# ¿Como puede realizar una consulta en un case when cuando obtengo múltiples resultado?

Tags: sql-server

Mi duda es la siguiente, estoy tratando de hacer una consulta  que pueda traer varios resultados

```
declare @uno int=1

                        select *from tblQuotation where IN_PricingID in(
                        case when @uno=0 then (3155)
                        else(select IdPricing from tblEcomerciaSsupportPricing where idSSuport=2027 and IdPricing is not null)
                        end
                        )
```

como se puede apreciar en mi código lo que deseo es que mi consulta a la **tblquotation** me traiga todos los resultados filtrados por los datos que me pueda traer el **else** que actualmente trae 2 , por lo que me bota el error de **"Subquery returned more than 1 value"**.
Lo que me gustaría saber es de que forma puedo escribir la consulta para que me permita traer los datos de la tabla utilizando el **where IN_PricingID in** y que utilice los valores del **else**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar And y Or en vez de case, ya que es más simple.

```
DECLARE @UNO INT = 1;
select *
       from tblQuotation
       where (IN_PricingID in
            (
             select IdPricing
                    from tblEcomerciaSsupportPricing
                    where idSSuport = 2027 and IdPricing is not null
            ) AND @UNO = 0) 
            OR 
            (IN_PricingID = 3155 AND @UNO = 1);
```

In_pricingId este en la lista de valores que devuelve la subconsulta y @uno sea 0
O
In_pricingId = 3155 y @uno sea 1